# Dimensions Of Fancybox With Html5 Video Bad Behavior In Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, html5-video, fancybox-2

I need to show an html5 video inside a fancybox when the video link is clicked.
If at first sight this might look like an already answered question, please read further, because i have made an extensive research of 15 sleepless hours. Ouch.

Here is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.3" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.3"></script>

<style type="text/css">
video {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
} 
   </style>

</head>
<body>

<a class="fancybox2" rel="group" title="Play Video" href="#data1">Play Video</a>

<div style="display:none"><div id="data1">
<video controls preload="none" poster="bathtub.jpg">
  <source src="bathtub.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="bathtub.webm" type="video/webm">
<embed src="bathtub.flv" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="360" allowscriptaccess="always" 

allowfullscreen="true" autoplay="false" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div></div> 


            <script type="text/javascript">




                jQuery(document).ready(function() {



                    // FANCY BOX ( LIVE BOX) WITH MEDIA SUPPORT
                    jQuery(".fancybox2").fancybox({
                        scrolling : 'no',
                        fitToView: 'true',
                        openEffect  : 'none',
                        closeEffect : 'none',
                        helpers : {
                            media : {}
                        }
                    });


                });


            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Since what i want to ultimately achieve is for the fancybox and its content html5 video to be responsive and therefore to have the html5 video filling the fancybox at any screen size, i have inserted that style for the video element in the header:

```
<style type="text/css">
video {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
} 
   </style>
```

Everything works fine in Chrome and IE: when i click on the video link, the fancybox opens up correctly, the html5 video and its poster and controls are shown correctly inside the fancybox, filling it, and when i resize the browser the fancybox scales accordingly and so does the html5 video which keeps filling the fancybox gracefully at any size.

**Firefox, however (latest version, 26), opens the fancybox at default size of 100X100 pixels with poster of html5 video scaled and fitting the fancybox and with controls not fitting fancybox size. In few words, on Firefox the fancybox opens too small as if Firefox did not pick the 640x360 size of the video element and therefore was pulling the default minimum size from its javascript file.
If i click on that little fancybox, the video starts and when it has started, if i resize the window, now FF resize both fancybox and video as expected.**

If i delete the video elemnet style, the fancybox opens as expected in all browsers, including Firefox, but when i resize the window, the video does not scale with the fancybox.

I have tried to use autoSize, autoResize, width and height in the fancybox call in any possible combination, but no success.

**How can i achieve to open the fancybox and have it sized according to the video element reserved space (640x360 in my case) and have everything scaling smoothly in different browser sizes in all browsers?**

Thanks in advance to everybody who will spend their time to drive me to the right direction. Hopefully jfk is around too.

Comment: where is your fancybox code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having tried the afterLoad solution suggested by Carl (without changing the Doctype, because as JFK stated that is not an option, at least in my case), things have remained more or less the same: the fancybox now opens at the specified width and height in Firefox even keeping the style of the video element, but that style gets ignored by all browsers and the video does not scale in a way that it fills the fancybox entirely, when the browser gets resized.

However, this has somehow switched the light for me and driven me to the right direction. Carl solution, keeping the original doctype, doesn't seem to work with html5 videos because no matter which width and height you indicated, the video always shows inside the fancybox at the width/height of its poster image ruling the fancybox aspect ration when you resize the browser.

**What i have done was to use ffmpeg to get frame width and height of the video, injecting them into the data-width and data-height of the fancybox anchor and adding `aspectRatio : true` to the fancybox javascript.**

Here is the complete fixed and working code (i use a custom ffmpeg class to retrieve the video info), if anybody had the same problem (in red are the additions/changes made, compared to the question code) :

```
**<?php 
include ("class/ffmpeg.class.php");
?>**

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.3" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.3"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    video {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    } 
       </style>

    </head>
    <body>

**<?php

// instantiate ffmpeg ultimate class
$ffmpegultimate = new FfmpegUltimate ();

$path_original = "bathtub.mp4";

$output = $ffmpegultimate->fileGetInfo ( $path_original );

$tarray = implode(" ", $output); 

preg_match('/(\d{2,4})x(\d{2,4})/', $tarray, $matches);

?>**

    <a class="fancybox2" rel="group" title="Play Video" href="#data1" **data-width="<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>" data-height="<?php echo $matches[2]; ?>"**>Play Video</a>

    <div style="display:none"><div id="data1">
    <video controls preload="none" poster="bathtub.jpg">
      <source src="bathtub.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="bathtub.webm" type="video/webm">
    <embed src="bathtub.flv" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="360" allowscriptaccess="always" 

    allowfullscreen="true" autoplay="false" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    </div></div> 


                <script type="text/javascript">




                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {




                    // FANCY BOX ( LIVE BOX) WITH MEDIA SUPPORT
                    jQuery(".fancybox2").fancybox({
                        scrolling : 'no',
                        fitToView: 'true',
                        openEffect  : 'none',
                        closeEffect : 'none',
                        helpers : {
                            media : {}
                        }**,
                        autoSize: false,
                        aspectRatio : true,
                        afterLoad: function () {
                            this.width = $(this.element).data("width");
                            this.height = $(this.element).data("height");
                        }**

                    });


                    });


                </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It remains to be seen why Firefox didn't like the code i posted in the question, but this solution works in all major browsers and therefore i am going to accept my own answer, hoping that someone else can benefit from it in the future. Thanks Carl for somehow contributing to this. I will try to +1 you if the system allows me as you have been of great help.

Comment: I never posted an answer because you never showed (neither in your question or answer) your fancybox code but I think the solution would have been simpler without `FfmpegUltimate`

Comment: What do you mean for fancybox code?                 `jQuery(document).ready(function() {



                    // FANCY BOX ( LIVE BOX) WITH MEDIA SUPPORT
                    jQuery(".fancybox2").fancybox({
                        scrolling : 'no',
                        fitToView: 'true',
                        openEffect  : 'none',
                        closeEffect : 'none',
                        helpers : {
                            media : {}
                        }
                    });


                });` This was both in question and answer. I don't understand.

Comment: I haven't accepted the answer yet, so if you have a better, simpler solution, please post it or/and let me know which fancybox code you need me to post.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some trouble with Fancybox. For my part I had to solve two problems with FF that helped me solve everything.

**First I added this**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

**Secondly I solved it by applying an afterload.**

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    scrolling:no,
    fitToView: true,
    autoSize: false,
    afterLoad: function () {
        this.width = $(this.element).data("width");
        this.height = $(this.element).data("height");
    }
});
```

Comment: personally I don't think changing the DOCTYPE is the way to go

Comment: @JFK No I agree but that was what worked for me. And if he/she stumbling on that it might just be worth it.